# How to Automate an Insert "UnKnown" row to the Dimension tables in MSSQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I have multiple dimension tables and insert script for all tables. i want to insert 1st row as "UNKNOWN" row. when we deploy all the dimension tables for multiple client the UNKNOWN row also should be inserted so How can i do rather manual insertion ?

```
INSERT INTO Dimension.table1(Column1, Column2,Column3, Effective)
VALUES ('<Unknown>', '<Unknown>', '<Unknown>',GetDate());


INSERT INTO Dimension.[Table2] (Column_A, Column_B,Column_C,Column_D, Column_E, Effective)
VALUES (0,'<Unknown>',0, '<Unknown>','<Unknown>', GetDate());

INSERT INTO Dimension.[Table3] (ColumnX, ColumnY,ColumnX, Effective)
VALUES ('<Unknown>', '<Unknown>', '<Unknown>',GetDate());
```

I have to automate this script for multiple client.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried?

Comment: You could use nulls instead of putting in place holder values that represent null, but hard to tell if that would work as you've not provided any schema or sample data

Comment: @Tanner I have added the sample plz refer. I can keep in text file and shell scrip to execute that file . can you suggest any easy way to automate .

Comment: @SchmitzIT I tried to write a Shell Script . But No idea about that that's why posted this question. In sql server  can we use  any function?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Create an insert script for every single table.  This is easier to program, but requires additional work for every new dimension added.
2. Create a script that dynamically identifies the dimensions, the key value and the appropriate 'Unknown' value based on data type for each attribute.  This can be very complicated to create, but is self maintaining as long as you don't add any new data types.

I expect the best choice will entirely depend on how many dimension tables you have, and how often you add new ones.

---

UPDATED

---

For what its worth, here is a stored procedure I wrote a few years ago.  I'm sure it could use some updating, and for some reason my system is no longer recognizing the line break characters, but it should get you pretty close.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDimSeedRecords]
    /*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Object Name: dbo.InsertDimSeedRecords
 Project: Enterprise Data Warehouse
 Purpose: Used to add seed rows to dimension tables, identified as tables prefixed with
            Dim or contained in the dim schema.
 Detailed description:
    1. Identifies all dimension tables based on the Table and Schema parameters
    2. Drops Constraints preventing changes to table data
    3. Deletes seed values or Truncates tables based on TruncateData parameter
    4. Generates new seed value insert statements
    5. Inserts new records into table.
    6. Re-create constraints
    7. Enable constraints (currently disabled)

 Example: 
 EXEC dbo.InsertDimSeedRecords
  @DimTableName = 'All',
  @Schema = 'All',
  @DisplayResults = 'Y',
  @ExecuteActions = 'N'

Parameters:
    DimTableName - Accepts the Table Name by itself or qualified with the schema name for backward compatibility.  
                        Values 'DimWorkOrder' and 'dbo.DimWorkOrder' will affect the same table.
                   'All' can be used to affect all dim tables in the specified schema.
    @Schema - The schema name to affect.  Ex: 'dim','dbo'; Default is 'dbo' 
    @TruncateData - If 'Y', truncates the dimension tables prior to reseeding.
                    If 'N', deletes the seed values (negative SK) from the table and inserts newly generated seed values.
                    Default is 'N'
    @DisplayResults - If 'Y', displays a detailed list of all actions executed/planned, including successful actions.  
                      If 'N', Successful actions are not displayed.  Default = 'N'
    @DisplayErrors - If 'Y', displays all ations that failed to execute, with error numbers and return codes
                    If 'N', no error details are returned, a ReturnCode is the only result set.  
                    Use 'N' in automated or scripted tasks
                    Default is 'N'
    @ExecuteActions - If 'N', all the tasks will be generated, but not executed.  Use this to check what actions would
                        be performed without making any changes.
                    If 'Y', all tasks will be executed.  
                    Default is 'Y' to allow for backward compatibility with previous versions
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rev | Date Modified | Developer     | Change Summary
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1  | 2013-11-01    | XXXXXXXX      | Created  

*/
    @DimTableName SYSNAME,
    @Schema SYSNAME = 'dbo',
    @TruncateData CHAR(1) = 'N',
    @DisplayResults CHAR(1) = 'N',
    @DisplayErrors CHAR(1) = 'N',
    @ExecuteActions CHAR(1) = 'Y'
AS
BEGIN
    --/*
    --*/
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ErrorLog') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #ErrorLog;
    END

    CREATE TABLE #ErrorLog (
        TableObject NVARCHAR(256),
        StepNum INT,
        StepCommand NVARCHAR(MAX),
        ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
        ErrorNumber INT,
        ErrorSeverity INT,
        ErrorState INT,
        ErrorLine INT,
        ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(200)
        );

    DECLARE @TableNameCRSR SYSNAME,
        @SchemaNameCRSR SYSNAME;

    DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR --Retrieve all tables to be affected
    FOR
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id),
        o.NAME
    FROM sys.objects AS O
    WHERE o.type = 'U' --U = User Table
        AND (
            --All Dim tables from All eligible schemas
            (
                @Schema = 'All'
                AND (
                    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = 'dim'
                    OR o.NAME LIKE 'Dim%'
                    )
                AND SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) <> 'ref'
                )
            --tables from a specific schema
            OR (
                SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @Schema
                AND (
                    -- A specific table
                    o.NAME = @DimTableName
                    -- All dim tables
                    OR (
                        @DimTableName = 'All'
                        AND (
                            o.NAME LIKE '%Dim%'
                            OR @Schema = 'dim'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            OR (SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.NAME = @DimTableName) --For legacy Schema Qualified @DimTableName values
            )
        AND NOT o.NAME IN (
            --Add excluded/protected tables here
            'MasterPackageControl', 'MasterPackageControl_Archive', 'ETLConfiguration', 'Date', 'Time'
            );

    OPEN Table_Cursor;

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Table_Cursor
    INTO @SchemaNameCRSR,
        @TableNameCRSR

    DECLARE @SQLCommand VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @ProcOrder CHAR(1);

    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Worker_Cursor CURSOR
            --Cursor to hold all of the commands in the correct processing order; 
            --this ensures that data is modified after constraints are dropped and before they are re-created, 
            --and that no constraint definitions are lost
        FOR
        WITH SQLConstraints
        AS (
            SELECT SQLDrop = 'RAISERROR (N''Dropping CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) + ''' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = Object_ID(N''[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) + ']'') AND parent_object_id =OBJECT_ID(N''[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + ']'') ' + ') 
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id)) + '' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'END
',
                SQLDisable = 'RAISERROR (N''Disabling CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) + ''' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = Object_ID(N''[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) + ']'') AND parent_object_id =OBJECT_ID(N''[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + ']'') ' + ') 
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id)) + '' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'END
' --+ ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                ,
                SQLAdd = 'RAISERROR (N''Creating CONSTRAINT [FK_' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '_' + C.NAME + '_' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) --+ '_' + RC.name
                + ']'' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + ' WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '_' + C.NAME + '_' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) --+ '_' + RC.name
                + '] FOREIGN KEY(' + QUOTENAME(C.NAME) + ') REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)) + '(' + QUOTENAME(RC.NAME) + ')
'
                --+ ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                ,
                LenConstraintName = LEN('FK_' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '_' + C.NAME + '_' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)),
                SQLEnable = 'RAISERROR (N''Enabling CONSTRAINT [FK_' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '_' + C.NAME + '_' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) --+ '_' + RC.name
                + ']'' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)) + ' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_' + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + '_' + C.NAME + '_' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) + OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) + ']

',
                NumRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id),
                        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)
                    ),
                ReferencedTable = OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id),
                ReferencedColumn = RC.NAME
            FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS FKC
            INNER JOIN sys.columns AS C
                ON fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
                    AND fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
            INNER JOIN sys.columns AS RC
                ON fkc.referenced_object_id = rc.object_id
                    AND fkc.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
            WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) = @SchemaNameCRSR
                AND OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) = @TableNameCRSR
            ),
        SQLTables
        AS (
            SELECT SQLTruncate = '
RAISERROR (N''TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ''' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '
',
                NumRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA,
                        TABLE_NAME
                    ),
                *
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
            WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'Base Table'
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaNameCRSR
                AND TABLE_NAME = @TableNameCRSR
            ),
        SQLInserts
        AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT SQLInsert = 'RAISERROR (N''Inserting ' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_NAME) + ''' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

' + CASE 
                    WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_NAME)), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
                        THEN 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_NAME) + ' ON 
'
                    ELSE ''
                    END + '
INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_NAME) + ' 
  ( ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING((
                            SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C2
                            WHERE c2.TABLE_NAME = c1.Table_name
                                AND c2.TABLE_SCHEMA = c1.table_schema
                            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 2, 16000) + ' 

)', ', ', CHAR(13) + SPACE(10) + ', ') + '
VALUES
(
            ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING((
                            SELECT ', ' + CASE 
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('ModifiedDate', 'UpdateAuditKey')
                                        THEN 'Null --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN C2.COLUMN_NAME IN ('CreatedDate', 'EffectiveDate')
                                        THEN '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 120) + ''' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('InsertAuditKey')
                                        THEN '0 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('CurrentIndicator')
                                        THEN '1 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('RowStamp')
                                        THEN '''-1'' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type = 'bit'
                                        THEN '1 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%char%'
                                        OR c2.data_type = 'ntext'
                                        THEN CASE 
                                                WHEN c2.character_maximum_length > 7
                                                    THEN '''Unknown'''
                                                WHEN c2.character_maximum_length > 2
                                                    THEN '''Unk'''
                                                ELSE '''U'''
                                                END + ' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%date%'
                                        THEN '''19000101'' --' + c2.column_name
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE 'tinyint'
                                        THEN '0 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%int%'
                                        THEN '-1 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type IN ('numeric', 'decimal', 'float')
                                        THEN '0 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%binary%'
                                        THEN 'cast(-1 as ' + DATA_TYPE + ISNULL('(' + CAST(Character_Maximum_length AS VARCHAR(5)) + '))', '') + ' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    END
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C2
                            WHERE c2.TABLE_NAME = c1.Table_name
                                AND c2.TABLE_SCHEMA = c1.table_schema
                            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 2, 16000) + ' 
),
', ', ', CHAR(13) + SPACE(10) + ', ') + '

(
            ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING((
                            SELECT ', ' + CASE 
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('ModifiedDate', 'UpdateAuditKey')
                                        THEN 'Null --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN C2.COLUMN_NAME IN ('CreatedDate', 'EffectiveDate')
                                        THEN '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 120) + ''' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('InsertAuditKey')
                                        THEN '0 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('CurrentIndicator')
                                        THEN '1 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.column_name IN ('RowStamp')
                                        THEN '''-2'' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type = 'bit'
                                        THEN '1 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%char%'
                                        OR c2.data_type = 'ntext'
                                        THEN CASE 
                                                WHEN c2.character_maximum_length > 13
                                                    THEN '''Not Applicable'''
                                                WHEN c2.character_maximum_length > 2
                                                    THEN '''N/A'''
                                                ELSE '''N'''
                                                END + ' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%date%'
                                        THEN '''18991231'' --' + c2.column_name
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE 'tinyint'
                                        THEN '0 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%int%'
                                        THEN '-2 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type IN ('numeric', 'decimal', 'float')
                                        THEN '0 --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    WHEN c2.data_type LIKE '%binary%'
                                        THEN 'cast(-2 as ' + DATA_TYPE + ISNULL('(' + CAST(Character_Maximum_length AS VARCHAR(5)) + '))', '') + ' --' + c2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    END
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C2
                            WHERE c2.TABLE_NAME = c1.Table_name
                                AND c2.TABLE_SCHEMA = c1.table_schema
                            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 2, 16000) + ' 

)
' + CASE 
                        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_NAME)), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
                            THEN 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c1.TABLE_NAME) + ' OFF 
'
                        ELSE ''
                        END + '
', ', ', CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + SPACE(10) + ', ')
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C1
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
                ON C1.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
                    AND C1.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
                    AND C1.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
            WHERE 1 = 1
                AND t.TABLE_TYPE <> 'VIEW'
                AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaNameCRSR
                AND t.TABLE_NAME = @TableNameCRSR
            ),
        SQLCleanKey
        AS (
            SELECT SQLCommand = 'RAISERROR (N''Delete keys from ' + QUOTENAME(tc.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(tc.TABLE_NAME) + ''' , 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TC.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TC.TABLE_NAME) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(ccu.COLUMN_NAME) + ' < 0'
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.constraint_column_usage AS CCU
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints AS TC
                ON CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                    AND CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                    AND CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
            WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaNameCRSR
                AND tc.TABLE_NAME = @TableNameCRSR
            ),
        CommandsUnioned
        AS (
            SELECT SQLCommand = SQLDrop,
                ProcOrder = 1
            FROM SQLConstraints
            WHERE @TruncateData = 'Y'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT SQLDisable,
                ProcOrder = 2
            FROM SQLConstraints
            WHERE @TruncateData = 'N'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT SQLTruncate,
                ProcOrder = 3
            FROM SQLTables
            WHERE @TruncateData = 'Y'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT SQLCommand,
                ProcOrder = 4
            FROM SQLCleanKey
            WHERE @TruncateData = 'N'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT SQLInsert,
                ProcOrder = 5
            FROM SQLInserts

            UNION ALL

            SELECT SQLAdd,
                ProcOrder = 6
            FROM SQLConstraints
            WHERE @TruncateData = 'Y'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT sqlenable,
                procorder = 7
            FROM sqlconstraints
            )
        SELECT SQLCommand,
            ProcOrder
        FROM CommandsUnioned
        ORDER BY ProcOrder,
            SQLCommand;

        OPEN Worker_Cursor

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM Worker_Cursor
        INTO @SQLCommand,
            @ProcOrder

        WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
                IF @ExecuteActions = 'Y'
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE (@SQLCommand);
                END

                INSERT INTO #ErrorLog (
                    TableObject,
                    StepNum,
                    StepCommand,
                    ErrorMessage,
                    ErrorNumber,
                    ErrorSeverity,
                    ErrorState,
                    ErrorLine,
                    ErrorProcedure
                    )
                VALUES (
                    QUOTENAME(@SchemaNameCRSR) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableNameCRSR),
                    CAST(@ProcOrder AS INT),
                    @SQLCommand,
                    ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(), '-'),
                    ERROR_NUMBER(),
                    ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                    ERROR_STATE(),
                    ERROR_LINE(),
                    ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-')
                    )
            END TRY

            BEGIN CATCH
                INSERT INTO #ErrorLog (
                    TableObject,
                    StepNum,
                    StepCommand,
                    ErrorMessage,
                    ErrorNumber,
                    ErrorSeverity,
                    ErrorState,
                    ErrorLine,
                    ErrorProcedure
                    )
                VALUES (
                    QUOTENAME(@SchemaNameCRSR) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableNameCRSR),
                    CAST(@ProcOrder AS INT),
                    @SQLCommand,
                    ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                    ERROR_NUMBER(),
                    ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                    ERROR_STATE(),
                    ERROR_LINE(),
                    ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-')
                    )
            END CATCH

            FETCH NEXT
            FROM Worker_Cursor
            INTO @SQLCommand,
                @ProcOrder
        END

        CLOSE Worker_Cursor;

        DEALLOCATE Worker_Cursor;

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM Table_Cursor
        INTO @SchemaNameCRSR,
            @TableNameCRSR
    END

    CLOSE Table_Cursor;

    DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor;

    DECLARE @ret_code INT;

    SELECT @ret_code = MAX(ISNULL(ErrorNumber, 0))
    FROM #ErrorLog;

    IF @DisplayResults = 'Y'
        OR @ret_code <> 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT TableObject,
            StepNum,
            ErrorMessage,
            ErrorNumber,
            ErrorSeverity,
            ErrorState,
            ErrorLine,
            ErrorProcedure,
            StepCommand
        FROM #ErrorLog
        WHERE (
                (
                    @DisplayErrors = 'Y'
                    AND ErrorNumber IS NOT NULL
                    )
                OR @DisplayResults = 'Y'
                )
        ORDER BY StepNum,
            TableObject,
            StepCommand
    END

    RETURN (@ret_code)
END

GO
```

Comment: Yes I need the 2nd option . need to create script that should identify the tables in given database and insert an one row . if column type is INT  then 0 or If column type is string "Known"